# How can I run background task in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I need some your helps :(

I tried to activate background task for Windows 8 to update tile regularly. 
And I could find the heplful link 'http://css.dzone.com/articles/how-create-debug-background'

All the things that I got in here are described below.

> > To make background task agent, I should make another project. It would be good with 'Windows Runtime Object'.
> >
> > I can make the agent by implementing interface 'IBackgroundTask'.
> >     Codes in 'IBackgroundTask.Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)' are regularly handled.
> >
> > To make it works, I should refer 'Background Task' in .appmanifest.
> >     Entry Point is combined with namespace and the class which implements 'IBackgroundTask'.

But, it doesn't work :(
Even I copied the sample file correctly, but it doesn't work at all.

I refered the link which contains a solution file that I did for this.
Please give me a help :)

http://sdrv.ms/UToyGu

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error or does the background task just never run?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Background Task Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) or the [quickstart guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

The "Test" project does not have a reference to "BackgroundService"

Right click References in the Test project -> Add Reference... -> Solution -> BackgroundService -> OK